# How does Mercy's damage buff interact with Genji's Deflect ability?

Tags: overwatch

When Genji uses his Deflect ability on an incoming projectile, what happens in the following situations?

- If Mercy was buffing the player who originally fired the projectile, does it retain the damage bonus after Genji deflects it?
- If Mercy is buffing Genji at the time he reflects the projectile, does it gain the damage bonus?

Answer (score 5):

I don't have the ability to test this, but based on my understanding of the game, I would guess that the projectile receives the damage boost if Mercy is buffing Genji, not the one who fired the projectile.

I'm basing this on the fact that Genji's deflect works by eliminating the enemy projectile and creating a new projectile fired by Genji, this is most obvious when [continuously deflecting a Junkrat projectile](https://gfycat.com/ReflectingAgedDrake). You can see that as long as the grenade is deflected, the timer is always reset and the projectile will never explode.

Now confirmed thanks to [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4m2fgj/myself_and_some_friends_tested_some_more_mercy/).

> Genji's Reflected Projectiles: Confirmed! Boosting a Genji as he reflects a projectile WILL increase the damage the target receives. We, unfortunately, did not test to see whether or not boosting the initial source of damage would increase it as well.

Comment: There's been a handful of videos of two Genjis playing "hot potato" with a projectile (a bomb or rocket, usually). I wonder if there was a Mercy buffing each of them if the single projectile's damage would skyrocket to D.Va mech explosion levels?

Comment: @MageXy That makes no sense, a boosted projectile will lose its boost when it's deflected.

Comment: Oh, good point. Somehow I got it in my head that Genji takes the current damage of the projectile and applies that to the one that is sent back... not sure where I got that from.