# How does the damage calculation of Genji's deflect work?

Tags: overwatch

Is it calculated based on the damage it would have done to the Genji, or is it recalculated after being deflected?

Some examples:

1. A Widowmaker shoots at Genji's head, but he reflects it into her torso. Critical hit or no?
2. An opponent is damage-boosted by Mercy and shoots at Genji, is the reflected projectile damage-boosted? (actually answered [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/267343/how-does-mercys-damage-buff-interact-with-genjis-deflect-ability)) How about if it was the Genji that was being damage-boosted instead?
3. What if Genji has an orb of discord when he deflects?

Anyone feel free to add any scenarios to this question.

I have strong guesses about how each of these would behave, but no conclusive evidence.

Comment: Because the question you linked is asking about a specific scenario and this one is asking about the general mechanics, these two questions are not technically duplicates... however, the answer in the other question already answers this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Genji's deflect damage calculation is done on impact.

Meaning :

- A Widowmaker shooting at Genji's head, will headshot **only if Genji's aimed at her head**
- An opponent is damage-boosted by Mercy and shoots at Genji, won't recieve the damage boosted effect unless Genji's himself is being boosted.
- The same applies for the orb of discord.

How it works :

Genji is destroying the projectile and sending another in the direction that he choses. So it becomes Genji's projectile and no one elses.

Zarya's grenades (which is a special projectile) will keep Zarya's charge when she fired it. Probably just copying the original projectile data. (See this question for more details : [Does Zaryas alt fire increase in damage when you gain energy after firing?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/289335/does-zaryas-alt-fire-increase-in-damage-when-you-gain-energy-after-firing/289345#289345) )

Answer (score 1):

1. No, it is not a critical hit. Actual damage is not calculated until the bullet hits the target, and in the case of Genji deflecting, the target hit is Widow's torso.
2. No, the reflected bullet is not damage-amplified... *unless* there is a Mercy boosting the deflecting Genji.
3. Whether Genji is affected by an Orb of Discord does not affect his damage output.

When a projectile hits Genji's deflect, the projectile is basically eliminated (similar to a D.Va's defense matrix nullifying it) and a new projectile is spawned using the original's *base* damage, heading in the direction of Genji's crosshairs. The new projectile is affected by any damage boosts/dampers currently affecting the Genji.